# Exception during PowerMock of HConnectionManager.class (HBase)

Tags: java, hbase, powermock

1. `PowerMockito.mockStatic(HConnectionManager.class);`
2. `when(HConnectionManager.createConnection(configuration)).thenReturn(hConnection)`

What are the ways to mock HBase related configuration files? As I get:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.mapr.fs.ShimLoader.load(ShimLoader.java:214)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.CoreDefaultProperties.<clinit>(CoreDefaultProperties.java:60)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:1857)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getProperties(Configuration.java:2072)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:2282)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResources(Configuration.java:2234)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getProps(Configuration.java:2151)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.get(Configuration.java:871)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTrimmed(Configuration.java:890)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getBoolean(Configuration.java:1291)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration.checkDefaultsVersion(HBaseConfiguration.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration.addHbaseResources(HBaseConfiguration.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration.create(HBaseConfiguration.java:118)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.<clinit>(HConnectionManager.java:266)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor35.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.newInstance(SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.java:45)
    at org.objenesis.ObjenesisBase.newInstance(ObjenesisBase.java:73)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.instance.ObjenesisInstantiator.newInstance(ObjenesisInstantiator.java:14)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.repackaged.ClassImposterizer.createProxy(ClassImposterizer.java:143)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.repackaged.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:58)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.repackaged.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:49)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.repackaged.CglibMockMaker.createMock(CglibMockMaker.java:24)
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockmaker.PowerMockMaker.createMock(PowerMockMaker.java:46)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:33)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:59)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1285)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1163)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct solution, but a reasonable workaround: I assume, you want to use PowerMock to test **your** code, that has to make this static call, to then use the result coming back from it.

So, instead of "directly" making this static call, you create a wrapper around this functionality, like:

```
interface ConnectionProvider {
  public HConneciotn createConnection(configuration);
```

and a corresponding class that implements that method (by actually makes the static call).

Now you can change your other production code to work with your that new interface; and now, all your client code can be tested without the need to user PowerMokito ... because there is no more static call.

Of course, you might want to use PowerMokito to ensure that your new wrapper implementation is doing exactly what you expect it to do.

Comment: The solution provided is called ServiceStub pattern. In this pattern the external dependencies are kept loosely coupled to your core architecture by using the interface and not the concrete implementation. This provides you to test the code without actual service running.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@SuppressStaticInitializationFor("org.apache.hadoop.conf.CoreDefaultProperties")` to suppress static initialisation of the `org.apache.hadoop.conf.CoreDefaultProperties`class. More information you may find in PowerMock [documentation](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/SuppressUnwantedBehavior).

If you've just started write your application then, the better way will be create a class wrapper which will encapsulate static call and the wrapper in your system. There is a good principal: [don't mock what you don't own](https://8thlight.com/blog/eric-smith/2011/10/27/thats-not-yours.html).

And for the wrapper you may write an integration test that will test that wrapper works as you expected and you system expected.